# Spring Data JDBC org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Could not read value rental_movie from result set

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, one-to-one, spring-data-jdbc

How to select query filter in **one-to-one** relationship with **Spring Data JDBC** ?

Schema looks like this, basically 2 tables where **Rental** references **Movie**

```
drop table if exists rental;
drop table if exists movie;

create table movie
(
    id          serial primary key,
    title       text,
    description text
);

create table rental
(
    movie    integer primary key references movie (id),
    duration text,
    price    integer
)
```

And my code looks like this

```
@Query("select * from movie where title = :title ")
fun findByTitle(@Param("title") title: String): List<Movie>
```

But got an exception **org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Could not read value rental_movie from result set!**

The example project on [GitHub](https://github.com/dabdraimov/spring_data_jdbc_one_to_one_filter).

**P.S** I am quite new to this and followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccxBXDAPdmo) to learn basics, please help me to do it in proper way

**Solution # 1**

Use the **@Query** like this, but still not so good since there can be a lot of columns inside second table

```
SELECT movie.*,
       rental.price    AS rental_price,
       rental.duration AS rental_duration,
       rental.movie    AS rental_movie
FROM movie
         LEFT OUTER JOIN rental ON rental.movie = movie.id
where movie.title = 'Matrix'
```

Comment: Maybe it's not the problem, but I think it should be more clear if you rename that column (movie), to be different from the name of other table

Comment: You select * from table movie but it doesn't have rental column. Seems you need to join with rental table on movie id first.

Comment: @mlc Yes, I tried with join and updated question with this solution, but don't know how to make it less code, since there can be a lot of columns but it is needed to have prefix on second table, rental.* is not working...

Comment: Can you also include the definition of `Movie` class?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution #1 is currently the correct way to do this.

Query must return columns for all simple properties of the aggregate root, and for all embedded or referenced entities.

If you don't want to do that you can alway specify your own [`RowMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/query/Query.html#rowMapperClass--) or [`ResultSetExtractor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/query/Query.html#resultSetExtractorClass--)

Let's assume the following classes (similar to those you probably have):

```
class Movie {

    @Id Long id;
    String title;

    @Embedded
    Actor with;

    Rental rental;
}

class Actor {
    String name;
}

class Rental {
    Integer price;
}
```

Your select needs to return the following columns:

1. `id` for the `id` property of `Movie`
2. `title` for the `title` property of `Movie`
3. `rental_price` for the `price` property of `Rental`. Note the prefix `rental comes from the property name`rental`not from the class name`Rental`.
4. `rental_movie` this column is an artificial id for `Rental` used to determine if there is a `Rental` at all or if `Movie.rental` is `null`. 
   The value is irrelevant except for the fact if it is `null` or not. 
   This column is not required if `Rental` has an id column.
5. `name` for the property `name` of the class `Actor`.

   *Note:* There is no prefix here. If you want a prefix, e.g. because a class is embedded multiple times you have to put that in the `@Embedded` annotation.

   _Note #1: There is no artificial id here. 
   For embedded classes there is the `onEmpty` attribute of the `@Embedded` annotation to control if when all properties are null, if the whole embedded class is `null` or if the embedded class gets instantiated with all properties set to `null`.

With Spring Data JDBC 1.x a missing column causes an exception as you have seen.

From Version 2.0 a missing column will be silently ignored and the property not set.

There is an issue to provide an easier way to define by just defining the where clause: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-225

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
data class Movie(
        @Id
        val id: Long?,
        val title: String,
        val description: String,
        val rental: Rental
)
```

I don't use Kotlin, but I think if you want to query Movie and Rental together, you have to use @OneToOne annotation. Something like(java):

```java
public class Movie {
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "moive", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Rental rental;
}
```

And your Rental class is not right, need movieId.

```java
public class Rental {

   ...
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
   private Movie movie;

}
```

you could check [some code example](https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-one-mapping-example/).

Comment: you are using JPA in your example, but I need Spring Data JDBC 

https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc

Comment: I got your questions, you could check Spring rowMappers https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.query-methods.at-query.custom-rowmapper, maybe this can solve your questions.